# why does my javascript remove card button only work the first time but send a type error on subsequent uses?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a library web application I am working on. There is a form that allows the user to add a book to the library and enter information about the book. Once the book is submitted a html card is generated on the webpage with a checkbox and a remove button. The remove button works on any card, however if I then use it to try to remove a second book i receive the error

```
"script.js:53 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at HTMLButtonElement.document.getElementById.onclick (script.js:53)
```

Any insight would be super awesome!

Javascript

```
// set up library 
let myLibrary = [];
let bookIndex = 0;
let buttonCount = 0;
//set up object


function Book(title, author, pages) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.pages = pages;
}


//add object to library
function addBookToLibrary(Book){
    myLibrary.push(Book);
    // track library index
    bookIndex = bookIndex + 1;
    // array to hold button IDs
    let buttonArray = [];
    // array to hold card IDs
    let cardArray = [];
    let cardID = "card:" + bookIndex;
    cardArray.push(cardID);
    buttonCount+=1;
    let buttonName = "button" + bookIndex;
    buttonArray.push(buttonName);

    let html =  `
      <entry id=${bookIndex}>
          <div>
          <h3>Title: ${Book.title}</h3>
          <h3>Author: ${Book.author}</h3>
          <h3>Pages: ${Book.pages}</h3>
          <input type="checkbox" id="readBox" name = "readBox" value="Read">
          <label for"readBox">Read</label><br>
          <button id=${buttonName}>Remove</button>
          </div>
      </entry>
      `;

      
    console.log(buttonArray);
    console.log(cardArray);


    var newEl = document.createElement("template");
    newEl.innerHTML = html.trim();
    document.getElementById('main').appendChild(newEl.content.firstChild);

    
    //create remove button function
    document.getElementById(buttonName).onclick = function() {

        let newErEl = document.getElementById(bookIndex);
        document.getElementById('main').removeChild(newErEl);

        console.log(myLibrary);

    }

}


function removeBook(Book){
    myLibrary.pop(Book);
}


//test books
let lotr = new Book('The Fellowship of the Ring', 'J.R.R. Tolkein', '423 pages');
let ender = new Book('Enders Game', 'Orson Scott Card', '324 pages');
let martian = new Book('The Martian', 'Anthony Weir', '369 pages');


addBookToLibrary(lotr);
addBookToLibrary(ender);
addBookToLibrary(martian);


const addBtn = document.getElementById("submit");
addBtn.onclick = function() {
    let a = document.getElementById("bookTitle").value
    let b = document.getElementById("bookAuthor").value
    let c = document.getElementById("bookPages").value
    let newBook = new Book(a, b, c);    
    addBookToLibrary(newBook);

    document.getElementById("bookTitle").value = ""
    document.getElementById("bookAuthor").value = ""
    document.getElementById("bookPages").value = ""
}


function openForm() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}


function submitForm(){
    let a = document.getElementById("bookTitle")
}


function closeForm() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Library</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "container" img src="images/bookShelf.jpeg">
            <div id = "titleCard"> My Library</div>
            <div id="main" class = "all-book-cards"></div>

            <button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()">Add Book</button>
            <div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
                <form action="index.html" class="form-container">
                    <h1>Add Book</h1>

                    <label for="bookTitle"><b>Title:</b></label>
                    <input id="bookTitle" type="text" placeholder="Enter Title" name="bookTitle" required>

                    <label for="bookAuthor"><b>Author:</b></label>
                    <input id="bookAuthor" type="text" placeholder="Enter Author" name="bookAuthor" required>

                    <label for="bookPages"><b>Pages:</b></label>
                    <input id="bookPages" type="text" placeholder="Enter Pages" name="bookPages" required>

                    <button id="submit" type="button" class="btn">Add</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
        <script src ="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.all-book-cards{
    width: 20em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}


entry {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: black;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: groove;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
   
}

{box-sizing: border-box;}


.open-button {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    padding:16px 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 23px;
    right: 28px;
    width: 90px;
}


.form-popup {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 15px;
    border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
    z-index: 9;
}

.form-container {
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
}


.form-container input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
    border: none;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

.form-container input[type=text]:focus {
    background-color: rgb(161, 161, 161);
    outline: none;
}

.form-container .btn {
    background-color: #04AA6d;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.form-container .cancel {
    background-color: red;
}

.form-container .btn:hover, .open-button:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}



/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #006468;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #006468;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error states is that you are trying to remove from html something, that isn't actually html element.

For example:

```
null.removeChild(child);
```

In `let newErEl = document.getElementById(bookIndex); document.getElementById('main').removeChild(newErEl);`, "bookIndex" is 3 (last index added) when the function is first called.

So instead of deleting the book you want, you always delete the one within the last index.

After that `bookIndex` isn't changed (still 3 in your example) - so it tries to remove an element that doesn't exist anymore.

The solution to that is to get the actual element that we want to remove.

```js
// set up library 
let myLibrary = [];
let bookIndex = 0;
let buttonCount = 0;
//set up object


function Book(title, author, pages) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.pages = pages;
}


//add object to library
function addBookToLibrary(Book){
    myLibrary.push(Book);
    // track library index
    bookIndex = bookIndex + 1;
    // array to hold button IDs
    let buttonArray = [];
    // array to hold card IDs
    let cardArray = [];
    let cardID = "card:" + bookIndex;
    cardArray.push(cardID);
    buttonCount+=1;
    let buttonName = "button" + bookIndex;
    buttonArray.push(buttonName);

    let html =  `
      <entry id=${bookIndex}>
          <div>
          <h3>Title: ${Book.title}</h3>
          <h3>Author: ${Book.author}</h3>
          <h3>Pages: ${Book.pages}</h3>
          <input type="checkbox" id="readBox" name = "readBox" value="Read">
          <label for"readBox">Read</label><br>
          <button id=${buttonName}>Remove</button>
          </div>
      </entry>
      `;

      
    console.log(buttonArray);
    console.log(cardArray);


    var newEl = document.createElement("template");
    newEl.innerHTML = html.trim();
    document.getElementById('main').appendChild(newEl.content.firstChild);

    
    //create remove button function
    document.getElementById(buttonName).onclick = function(ev) { //ev here is the event happening

        let newErEl = ev.target.parentNode.parentNode; //ev.target - is our `remove` button that we pressed. We take its parent, that we want to remove (but since its parent is a div also has a parent that we want gone - we take the highest parent - `entry`)
        document.getElementById('main').removeChild(newErEl); //then we delete the actual element

        console.log(myLibrary);

    }

}


function removeBook(Book){
console.log('Library', myLibrary)
    myLibrary.pop(Book);
}


//test books
let lotr = new Book('The Fellowship of the Ring', 'J.R.R. Tolkein', '423 pages');
let ender = new Book('Enders Game', 'Orson Scott Card', '324 pages');
let martian = new Book('The Martian', 'Anthony Weir', '369 pages');


addBookToLibrary(lotr);
addBookToLibrary(ender);
addBookToLibrary(martian);


const addBtn = document.getElementById("submit");
addBtn.onclick = function() {
    let a = document.getElementById("bookTitle").value
    let b = document.getElementById("bookAuthor").value
    let c = document.getElementById("bookPages").value
    let newBook = new Book(a, b, c);    
    addBookToLibrary(newBook);

    document.getElementById("bookTitle").value = ""
    document.getElementById("bookAuthor").value = ""
    document.getElementById("bookPages").value = ""
}


function openForm() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
}


function submitForm(){
    let a = document.getElementById("bookTitle")
}


function closeForm() {
    document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.all-book-cards{
    width: 20em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}


entry {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: black;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: groove;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
   
}

{box-sizing: border-box;}


.open-button {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    padding:16px 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 23px;
    right: 28px;
    width: 90px;
}


.form-popup {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 15px;
    border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
    z-index: 9;
}

.form-container {
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
}


.form-container input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
    border: none;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}

.form-container input[type=text]:focus {
    background-color: rgb(161, 161, 161);
    outline: none;
}

.form-container .btn {
    background-color: #04AA6d;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.form-container .cancel {
    background-color: red;
}

.form-container .btn:hover, .open-button:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}



/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #006468;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #006468;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Library</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "container" img src="images/bookShelf.jpeg">
            <div id = "titleCard"> My Library</div>
            <div id="main" class = "all-book-cards"></div>

            <button class="open-button" onclick="openForm()">Add Book</button>
            <div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
                <form action="index.html" class="form-container">
                    <h1>Add Book</h1>

                    <label for="bookTitle"><b>Title:</b></label>
                    <input id="bookTitle" type="text" placeholder="Enter Title" name="bookTitle" required>

                    <label for="bookAuthor"><b>Author:</b></label>
                    <input id="bookAuthor" type="text" placeholder="Enter Author" name="bookAuthor" required>

                    <label for="bookPages"><b>Pages:</b></label>
                    <input id="bookPages" type="text" placeholder="Enter Pages" name="bookPages" required>

                    <button id="submit" type="button" class="btn">Add</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
        <script src ="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```